# dart modulo operator circular list

Tags: dart

I want to use the modulo (%) operator in order to access to list items in a circular way. But the code below doesn't work:

```
void main() {
  List<String> myList = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  int currIdx = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    print(myList[currIdx]);
    currIdx = currIdx++ % myList.length;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution: instead of coding

```
currIdx++
```

you must code

```
++currIdx
```

Complete code:

```
void main() {
  List<String> myList = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
  int currIdx = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    print(myList[currIdx]);
    currIdx = ++currIdx % myList.length; // look second comment below which is very useful !
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's also important to emphasize that `currIdx++` returns the current value, then increments, whereas `++currIdx` increments the value, then returns it.

Comment: Using `currIdx = ++currIdx % myList.length` is bad style.  You'd be updating `currIdx` twice in a single statement, which at best is wasteful and potentially confusing.  It would instead be far more idiomatic to write `currIdx = (currIdx + 1) % myList.length;`.